# Response.RedirectToRoute(RouteData.Values) redirects to the Area controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am trying to setup a BaseController to handle culture as part of the url (based on [ASP.NET MVC 5 Internationalization](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx)). My implementation works properly as long as I disable my Areas' registration.

When One of my Area is registered, if I try to input a wrong/not supported culture (http://localhost:52639/zz/), I experience a 404 error with a request URL: http://localhost:52639/fr/Test/Post.

I have checked my routes are properly registered.

If I do the same while disabling the Areas registration, the base controller and routing behave correctly if I type the following URL: http://localhost:52639/zz/ I am redirected to http://localhost:52639/fr/ (default culture).

**Those are my routes:**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var namespaces = new[]{typeof(PostController).Namespace};

        routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("PostToHack", "{culture}/Post/{idAndSlug}", new { culture = "", Controller = "Post", Action = "Show" }, namespaces);
        routes.MapRoute("Post", "{culture}/Post/{id}-{slug}", new { culture = "", Controller = "Post", Action = "Show" }, namespaces);

        routes.MapRoute("TagToHack", "{culture}/Tag/{idAndSlug}", new { culture = "", Controller = "Post", Action = "Tag" }, namespaces);
        routes.MapRoute("Tag", "{culture}/Tag/{id}-{slug}", new { culture = "", Controller = "Post", Action = "Tag" }, namespaces);

        routes.MapRoute("Logout", "{culture}/Logout", new { culture = "", Controller = "Authentication", Action = "Logout" }, namespaces);
        routes.MapRoute("Login", "{culture}/Login", new { culture = "", Controller = "Authentication", Action = "Login" }, namespaces);

        //Error routes
        routes.MapRoute("Error404", "{culture}/errors/404", new { culture = "", Controller = "Errors", Action = "NotFound" }, namespaces);
        routes.MapRoute("Error500", "{culture}/errors/500", new { culture = "", Controller = "Errors", Action = "Error" }, namespaces);

        routes.MapRoute("Home", "{culture}", new { culture = "", Controller = "Post", Action = "Index"},namespaces);

        //Never to be called by user which is why it comes after MapRoute Home so it is always overwritten by it
        routes.MapRoute("Sidebar", "{culture}", new { culture = "", Controller = "Layout", Action = "Sidebar"},namespaces);//This is a "child-only" controller
        routes.MapRoute("NavigationBar", "{culture}", new { culture = "", Controller = "Layout", Action = "NavigationBar"},namespaces);//This is a "child-only" controller
```

**Area Route**

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        var namespaces = new[] { typeof(PostsController).Namespace };

        context.MapRoute(
            "admin_default",
            "{culture}/admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { culture = "", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, namespaces
            );
    }
```

**Base Controller:**

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        var cultureName = RouteData.Values["culture"] as string;

        // Attempt to read the culture cookie from Request
        if (cultureName == null)
            cultureName = (Request.UserLanguages != null) && (Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0)
                ? Request.UserLanguages[0]
                : null; // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages

        // Validate culture name
        cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // This is safe


        if (RouteData.Values["culture"] as string != cultureName)
        {
            // Force a valid culture in the URL
            RouteData.Values["culture"] = cultureName.ToLowerInvariant(); // lower case too

            // Redirect user
            Response.RedirectToRoute(RouteData.Values);
        }

        // Modify current thread's cultures            
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I have found a solution that work for me. My issue was coming from the order in which I was registering my routes. I was registering my Area's routes first:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

I inverted the order and made sure that I was only registering my Area's routes after:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();            
    }
```